# Optimizing a triple loop to create a filter that reduces the size of an object in a 3D image

Tags: python, image, mask

I am a beginner in Python and I cannot optimize this function :

```py
def remove_voxels(volume):
    result = np.copy(volume
    for z in range(2, volume.shape[0] - 2):
        for y in range(2, volume.shape[1] - 2):
            for x in range(2, volume.shape[2] - 2):
                if ((volume[z - 2:z + 3, y - 2:y + 3, x - 2:x + 3]) == 
                     0).any():
                    result[z, y, x] = 0
    return result
```

I tried this :

```py
def remove_voxels(volume):
    result = np.copy(volume
    z, y, x = np.meshgrid(
       np.arange(2, volume.shape[0] - 2),
       np.arange(2, volume.shape[1] - 2),
       np.arange(2, volume.shape[2] - 2),
       indexing='ij')
   mask = ((volume[z - 2:z + 3, y - 2:y + 3, x - 2:x + 3]) == 0).any(axis= 
   (1, 2, 3))
   result[z[mask], y[mask], x[mask]] = 0
```

But I have this problem :

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

How can I optimize?

I have a 3D image containing an object in its center, and the values outside the object are zero. The values forming the edges of the object are incorrect up to 2 voxels from the edges. Therefore, I want to set them to 0. "Volume" refers to my image.

Comment: Hi! a couple of questions/remarks :  
1. Can you clarify what you mean by 'reduce the size' ? 
2. Could you please provide a minimum runnable example? 
3. It would also be nice if you could edit your question to format your code properly, so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the image processing operation you are looking for is called **erosion**.
Scipy has a [nice, fast implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy-ndimage-binary-erosion) of it, which will save you a lot of trouble.

As you have not provided any sample data, i'll put a short script illustrating it below.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion

# outline of this example taken and adapted from
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels.html

# prepare some coordinates
x, y, z = np.indices((20, 20, 20))

# draw 9x9x9 cube - this is our 'image' we want to erode. 
cube = (5 < x) & (x < 15) & (5 < y) & (y < 15) & (5 < z) & (z < 15)

# structuring element is a 5x5x5 cube
st = np.ones((5, 5, 5))

# erode the cube, removing 2 voxels from the edges
eroded_cube = binary_erosion(cube, st)

# and plot everything
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131, projection='3d')
ax1.voxels(cube, edgecolor='k')
ax1.set_title("original cube (9x9x9)")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132, projection='3d')
ax2.voxels(st, edgecolor='k')
ax2.set_title("structuring element")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133, projection='3d')
ax3.voxels(eroded_cube, edgecolor='k')
ax3.set_title("eroded cube (3x3x3)")

plt.show()
```

[image: plot of the output]

Your `remove_voxels` function would thus become :

```py
def remove_voxels(volume): 
    st = np.ones((5, 5, 5))
    eroded_volume = binary_erosion(volume, st)
    return eroded_volume
```

Comment: Thks for this ! I didn't know binary_erosion !